# MFmailcomposer works fine in iphone but not in simulator!

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, iphone

MFMailcomposer works fine in iphone but when run in simulator mails are not sent. and when sent from iphone if image is attached in mail it displays broken image. image is not clear.
i am not getting what is the problem. right now i dont have device and from simulator its not sending mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mail support in the simulator, so you can't send mail. And the broken image from a device is usually just a problem with the iPhone OS, when viewing the email on a desktop computer it should look fine. Nothing you can fix though.